# Google Sheets: How to Filter by Condition for Multiple Values Including a Wildcard?

Tags: google-sheets

We are trying to filter data in a report based upon campaign UTMs. In column C I want to include the following values:

1. bi_
2. fb_***var_di*
3. *se*
4. media_
5. zb_

This required using multiple values and wildcards as part of the filter.

I turn on the filter, click the triangle to the right of column C heading, select "Filter by Condition", use to the drop down for "Custom Data", and tried the following:

=OR(REGEXMATCH(C:C,"bi_"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"fb_***var_di*"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"*se*"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"media_"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"zb_"))

Unfortunately it doesnt work. Anyone have suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

*quite a few characters alike these **`[ ] { } ( ) ^ $ | ? * + &`** should have a escape character `\` preceding the said characters as they serve a different purpose within regex. so your current formula should work with:*

```js
=OR(REGEXMATCH(C:C,"bi_"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"fb_\*\*var_di"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"se"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"media_"),REGEXMATCH(C:C,"zb_"))
```

***OR** it can shortened as such:*

```js
=OR(REGEXMATCH(C:C,"bi_|fb_\*\*var_di|se|media_|zb_"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I tried that and everything works except the portion for fb. Basically I am trying to use wildcards for the different state abbreviations. For example there is fb_ct_var_di_ and fb_md_var_di_ and fb_nj_var_di_ and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: the provided formula is tested against the sample data provided in the post description [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/DVQRdh9.png)

Comment: I just updated the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/vebsHLt). I was hoping to use the "**" as a wildcard for the state abbreviations. When I test the code you provided it works for everything except the "fb" one. Do wildcards not work in filters?

    =OR(REGEXMATCH(C:C,"bi_|fb_\*\*_var_di_|_se_|media_|zb_"))

Comment: In column C its `fb_**_var_di_` and within formula you are using `fb_\*\*var_di_` (underscore missing)